# Why is my ggplot2 bar graph not displaying?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot bar graphs in ggplot2 and running into an issue.

Starting with the variables as this

```
PalList <- c(9, 9009, 906609, 99000099)
PalList1 <- as_tibble(PalList)
Index <- c(1,2,3,4)
PalPlotList <- cbind(Index, PalList)
PPL <- as_tibble(PalPlotList)
```

and loading the tidyverse `library(tidyverse)`, I tried plotting like this:

```
PPL %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=PalList)) +
  geom_bar()
```

It doesn't matter whether I'm accessing PPL or PalList, I'm still ending up with this (axes and labels may change, but not the chart area):
[image: Blank chart]

Even this still gave a blank plot, only now in classic styling:

```
ggplot(PalList1, aes(value)) +
  geom_bar() +
  theme_classic()
```

If I try `barplot(PalList)`, I get an expected result. But I want the control of ggplot. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to specify the `x`, `y` in `aes`, create the `geom_bar` with `stat` as 'identity', and change the x-axis tick labels

```
library(ggplot2)   
ggplot(PPL, aes(x = Index, y = PalList)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
     scale_x_continuous(breaks = Index, labels = PalList)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why I couldn't make it work on PalList1?

Comment: @DavidMVermillion `barplot` can take a named vector or formula or even a vector without any name.  In ggplot, the x and y should be provided